# TypeError missing 1 required positional argument for pysrim package

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I am trying to take advantage of the [pysrim](https://pypi.org/project/pysrim/) package to run some batch simulations of [SRIM/TRIM](http://www.srim.org/)  in Jupyter notebook. I was able to successful install both the program and the package but am getting an error "TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'" when using pysrim. Initially I assumed my Python version was to up to date (3.9.12) but am still getting this issue even after setting up a 3.6 environment. I understand this is a most likely a pretty niche question but any help would be much appreciated. Code pasted below.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from srim import TRIM, Ion, Layer, Target
from srim.output import Results
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this really all the code?  You're getting the error from just these import statements?

Comment: Hi John, yep the issue is from the "from srim import TRIM, Ion, Layer, Target
from srim.output import Results" lines.

Comment: Looks like _pysrim_ bug to me.

Comment: Did you read  any  file?  Or did you use  those modules  in anyway? . If yes,  then you will  have to provide some additional code and show  how you implemented those imported modules.  If not,  it will  really  be hard  to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay looks like I needed to change a small part of the program. I first navigated to `C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\srim\core` and opened the file `elementsdb.py`. On line 10 I changed `return yaml.load(open(dbpath, "r"))` to
`return yaml.full_load(open(dbpath, "r"))` and the issue was resolved.